# "Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main"." error in visual studio

Tags: python

I am using visual studio code and every time i run python code it says

```
"ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".".
```

I have reinstalled python, repaired it with the python installer exe thingy. When i reinstalled python i got another error saying i didn't have uvicorn installed so i installed it but now i am getting this error. It even happens when just running

```py
print("Test")
```

I was on python 3.10 but when i reinstalled i went to 3.11, still happened.

i tried to run code and i got an error. i was expecting it to work.

Comment: Can you provide content of requirements.txt and directory structure? Uvicorn is not needed by python by default, so problem needs to be in some part of project.